# Dimensionality reduction of speech data achieved after MFCC implimentaion

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

I have my speech data of sizes `(24*500)` or `(24*450)` or `(24*...)` obtained by **MFCC**.

What should I do for dimensionality reduction of data, such that reduced data should provide better classification results in speech recognition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to reduce dimensions of mfcc outputs of speech signal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092317/how-to-reduce-dimensions-of-mfcc-outputs-of-speech-signal)

Comment: improved formatting and gramatic appeal